# Why does the visual of this directive not line up with the value

Tags: angularjs

http://plnkr.co/edit/VAE43y5cagCF8jq5AlaY?p=preview

Within the directive, I'm using scope.$apply().  However, if you click too quickly it changes the value but not the visual affect.  This problem seems to be related to timing.  If I load the page and let it sit for 2 seconds the first click changes the value.  However, if I try to click it too quickly, it'll change the value without changing the visuals.

Can anyone explain this?  I'm thinking it might be mid-digest cycle or something like that, but can't say for sure and I'm not sure what to do about it...

```
            //toggle the state when clicked
            el.bind('click', function () {
                scope.$apply(function () {
                  var getter=$parse(attrs.ngModel);
                  var setter=getter.assign;
                  setter(scope,!getter(scope));
                    //scope[attrs.ngModel] = !scope[attrs.ngModel];
                    if (el.hasClass('on')) {
                        off();
                    } else {
                        on();
                    }
                });
            });
```

Comment: Hmm..even if I let the page sit for a couple of seconds, the first click only changes the text, not the visual, FYI

Comment: The first click image should be inactive not active.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the controller `$viewValue` instead of using `attrs[ngModel]`. It is more efficient when updating controller `scopes`. So instead of parsing and assigning with parse and other stuff you can just set the new value.

First we need `ngModel` controller.

```
require: '^ngModel',
```

Then we simply set the new value of the scope.

```
el.bind('click', function () {
    scope.$apply(function () {
         ctrl.$setViewValue(!ctrl.$viewValue);
    });
});
```

And we $watch the model attribute.

```
scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function (oldValue, newValue) {
   if (newValue) {
      off();
   } else {
      on();
   }
});
```

I forked your [**plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/Zwu7EcfkolSOlquc5aoh?p=preview)

Comment: I had made changes to this prior to your answer.  So I went ahead and tried to merge our 2 changes and it works, but not on the first click.  Any suggestions?  http://plnkr.co/edit/xqYBnz5BHLP844kXJXKs?p=preview

Comment: I found it! $watch retrue 'newValue' first. Here's the plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/XvVQgCJDAN1KKvoMAZEY?p=preview

Comment: BTW change only the value on click, do not trigger on() or off(), $watch will trigger it